# how are directories implemented in UNIX filesystem?

Tags: file, filesystems, directory

This question is extension to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18605/how-are-directories-implemented-in-unix-filesystems

I'm aiming to implement basic filesystem: After reading inode number and name we come to know Name of file and hence we can list directory contents but we can't determine type of entry: whether it's a file or a file.
If there are 1000 entries in directory then reading 1000 inodes just to determine whether it is file or directory looks too silly.

Am I missing something here or it is this way only?

Comment: As answered at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68467/34504
Its a design choice.

Comment: So if you feel that the information is too scattered around the filesystem then store it differently. You are the file system's designer. You are the one who gets to decide what data structures it will use, where they live, and what's in them!